# Instantiate DefaultBoundedRangeModel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I'm building an extremely simple GUI in netbeans with a slider that adjusts a progress bar.

I'm being asked to "Add a DefaultBoundedRangeModel myModel, as an instance property.  Initialize it to a range of 0 to 1000, with an extent of 100, and a current value of 123"

Would that just look like:

```
myModel = new DefaultBoundedRangeModel(0, 1000, 100, 123);
```

?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: @user3110424 is that how you would instantiate it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have seen the document for [DefaultBoundedRangeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultBoundedRangeModel.html). It says how to initialize it

```
public DefaultBoundedRangeModel(int value,
                    int extent,
                    int min,
                    int max)
```

> Initializes value, extent, minimum and maximum. Adjusting is false. Throws an IllegalArgumentException if the following constraints aren't satisfied:

`min <= value <= value+extent <= max`

So you have to instantiate your `DefaultBoundedRangeModel` keeping  this `min <= value <= value+extent <= max` in your mind.

Hope this help